# Sewer Line Opening - Makeshift Vent or Rodents?

Tags: plumbing, crawlspace, sewer, mice

In the crawl space beneath my house, the sewer line has a branch that runs right to the crawl space entry/vent. The end cap has a jagged hole:

[image: Sewer Line Image 1]

[image: Sewer Line Image 2]

Not sure if it's been that way since I bought it (recently). There are definitely signs of rodents nearby in the crawl space, and my guess is they made this opening. Am inclined to replace this rubber end cap with a hard PVC clean-out end-cap. But am wondering if there's a chance this is a makeshift vent by the prior owner? (And if it were, why not just remove the end cap instead of gutting a hole in it)?

What do you think? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I'm pretty sure that's rodent work right there

The scalloped, somewhat irregularly-shaped nature of the hole makes me think it was made by some rodent somewhere trying to avoid a nasty dental bill.  (Rodents need to gnaw to keep their front teeth from growing off into the other jaw.)  I would replace it with a hard PVC endcap or cleanout, as vents need to vent up so that you don't have nasty sewer gasses floating around at ground level.